# Can´t link a view with another class. Beginner XD

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

X-) I have some trouble trying to solve this, I have my rootviewcontroler main class, and from there a navigationController with 3 TabBars, but when I want to load that tabbar view from a different class or xib. actually, I can´t...Even in the interface builder it says VIEW LOADED FROM "PAQUETES" but when I build it, it chrashes and with the debugger console it says this:

*[Session started at 2012-05-05 02:52:04 +0000.]
2012-05-04 21:52:54.231 Zoo[2263:9203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "paquetes" nib but the view outlet was not set.'*

Though I dont understand What it means, because normally to change a different xib. view you just change the NIB name right?
So...
thanks XD

Answer (score 0):

Go to your XIB file in Interface Builder and do the following 2 steps:

-Set the "Class" to the name of your UIViewController class (this is set in the "Identity Inspector - click File's Owner then the third little icon on the right panel)
-Connect the "view" Outlet to the main view of your XIB (this is set in the "Connections Inspector - click File's Owner then the last little icon on the right panel)

That should do it.

Comment: Let me see if I get it, I have only two classes: the main one, the rootviewcontroller (ZooViewController) and the "paquetes" class which is a UITableViewController, but in my main class as you told me it is set like that to my main class and the view too and I did the same for the other xib. the "paquetes" one because it´s class was paquetes so I changed it to the ZooViewController class and linked the view, but it still gives me the same error in the debugger console and it still chrashes, anything else you think I may be doing wrong...

Comment: When you created your view controllers, did you check the box to generate the XIB with the view controller, or did you create the views separately?

Comment: Check View Exist or not and  whether it is connected with self.view property.

Comment: Yes I created the view controller with the xib...@Mangesh vyas, sorry but I didnt get your comment